Get font sizes from font name
If I have a font A and font B in a Qt based program, do they have different sizes?
I'm on KDE, and I need to know the list of font sizes available for the font name.
As an example:
On Windows, selecting different font names changes the font size list selection. However, on GTK, the font sizes are pretty much the same.
I think OSX behaves like GTK — changing the font name doesn't change the size list.
What about Qt?
And if it follows Windows — how do I find the list of sizes?

Check all QFont related classes (specifically, QFontMetrics, QFontInfo and QFontDatabase) and study their documentation. Besides, most programs just provide an arbitrary list of common sizes, as fonts are normally scalable.

If you want to know the font size for each font across Qt, you can use the QFontDatabase class. This class provides information about available fonts, including the sizes supported by a particular font family.
If you want to get the area size by font, you can use the QFontMetrics class. QFontMetrics allows you to know the size of an area using a string and font name.
